# What does this javascript regex do?

Tags: javascript, regex

what does this mean?

```
name = name. replace(/([A-Z]) /g, " -$1" );
```

it's js.

correction i meant `name = name.replace(/([A-Z]) /g, "-$1" );`

Comment: is that JavaScript? Regex can be formatted differently depending on what programming language you're representing it in.

Answer (score 2):

It means:

> Take the string "name," and look for each uppercase letter followed by a space.  When you find one occurrence, replace it with a hyphen, then the letter.  Once you've done that for all occurrences, assign this new string back to the "name" variable.

For example, if "name" is `AB CD` before this line is executed, "name" will be `A-BCD` after this line is executed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the /g means it's just at the end of the string, no? I tested this real quick in javascript and: "HEllo MY friends" was replaced with "HEllo M -Y friends".

Comment: @Matt: It looks for each uppercase letter followed by a space, and the space is removed.

Comment: Javascript may not recognise the /g flag. If it's something like Perl then /g means global.

Comment: I screwed up the regex.  There's a space in the parens after the [A-Z].  The g means "global" in PERL.  So the pattern is looking for capital letters that are followed by a space.

Comment: @Gazillion: No. The `g` at the ends means it's "gobal", thus it's repeated for all occurrences of the expression instead of only the first.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, the `[A-Z]` means match any upper-case letter, the `/g` bit means do it globally (the entire input string), and the `-$1` bit means replace each matching group `X` with `-X`. `$1` refers to the bit in parenthesis in the first argument.

So, if the input is "HE LLO" you'll get "H-E LLO" out. If the input is "He LL o" you should get "He L-L o" out.

I'd recommend you read up on regular expressions since they can be very complex.

Comment: What do you mean by? $1 refers to the bit in parenthesis in the first argument.

Comment: `$1` is what's called a "backreference". Each pair of parenthesis defines a backreference that can be later referred to by the `$n` syntax. The first backreference is `$1`, the second is `$2` and so on. So the "replace" part of the expression refers to the first backreference in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

After `(A-Z)` is a space. So it should only match uppercase characters followed by a space. Those are replaced by " -" and the original character (backreference). So for the string "HELLO MY Friends" the result would be `HELL -OM -YFriends`. the `/g` means global, so replace all occurences.

Tried it in perl:

```
$var = "HELLO MY Friends";
$var =´ s/([A-Z]) / -$1/g;
print $var . "\n";
```